# Find the maximum value in each row in a matrix that includes NAs

Tags: r, matrix, max, na

I am trying to find the maximum value in each row in a matrix in r when the matrix includes NA's.

I tried to use the function rowMax() from the "qlcMatrix" package, but it doesn't handle NA's (it gives me back "NA" if the row contain at least one NA value).

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: `library(matrixStats); rowMaxs(x, na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 5):

Sotos' answer above works. Also check the documentation for 'apply' in base R:

```
apply(your_matrix, 1, max, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use max.  If you provide the row as a vector and use max just make sure you set na.rm = TRUE.

Here is an example using a vector:

```
> x = c(2,4,6,10,1,5,NA)

> max(x,na.rm = TRUE)

[1] 10
```

Here is an example using a matrix:

```
> x = matrix(1:10,2,5)
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    3    5    7    9
[2,]    2    4    6    8   10
> x[2,2] = NA
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    3    5    7    9
[2,]    2   NA    6    8   10
> max(x[2,],na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 10
```

Here is a simple for loop demonstration:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
    y[i] = max(x[i,],na.rm = TRUE)

}
> y
[1]  9 10
```

Comment: They need it for each row though...

Comment: No problem I added that, I had figured that his issue was more with the lack of NA support than the loop.

Comment: That not a good way. `print` isn't storing values anywhere, hence it is useless.

Comment: Print was just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: So what is the solution then? If they can't use neither `print` or `y`. See [this](https://datalearner.wordpress.com/2013/08/06/efficient-r-preallocating-memory-for-matrices/) for instance

Comment: I was really just trying to show them that they can see the result as it went through the loop.  I have since changed it.  In all fairness the issue was really with the NA's.